# talend api test set up error. but working in postman

Tags: rest, amazon-ec2, postman, talend

This is done by Postman. Like this, 200 OK comes up well.

However, there is an error when I run it on **'Talend API Tester'.**

If you look here, the content type of Headers and Body is different.

<postman- headers: Content Type: multipart

postman-body: ContentType: application/json>

[image: postman - headers]

[image: postman - body]

I don't know how to run this on Talend API Tester.

It can't be set separately here.

[image: talend api tester]

So there is a 500 or 415 error now.

I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how to specify it in Talend API Tester.